# BroadcastReceiver not registering with Intent - Wifi Scanning

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-wifi

I have setup a basic app to scan and display the details of Wifi AP's in range. I used a broadcast receiver to refresh the list whenever a scan is completed. However, the receiver is not getting registered as both .startScan() as well as starting the scan from the inbuilt GUI are not trigerring the onReceive() method of the receiver.

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    WifiManager mainWifi;
    IntentFilter filter;
    boolean intentIsRegistered = false;

    private BroadcastReceiver wifiEventReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.e("DEBUG", "Update received!");
            if(intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)) {
                Log.e("DEBUG","SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION");
                List<ScanResult> li = mainWifi.getScanResults();
                for (int i=0; i<li.size(); i++) {
                    Log.e("DEBUG","ssid: "+li.get(i).SSID+" bssid: "+li.get(i).BSSID+" cap: "+li.get(i).capabilities+" level: "+li.get(i).level+ "chan: "+li.get(i).frequency);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       // Button wifiConnect = (Button)findViewById(R.id.WifiConnect);
        mainWifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

        if(mainWifi.isWifiEnabled()==false){
            Log.e("DEBUG","turning on wifi");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enabling Wifi...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mainWifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
        } else {
            Log.e("DEBUG","wifi is on");
        }

        if (mainWifi.startScan() == false) {
            Log.e("Error","Scanning could not start");
        } else {
            Log.e("DEBUG", "Scanning has started");
//            mainText.setText("Starting Scan...");
        }


        filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(wifiEventReceiver, filter);
        intentIsRegistered = true;
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Refresh");
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        mainWifi.startScan();
        return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (intentIsRegistered==true) {
            unregisterReceiver(wifiEventReceiver);
            intentIsRegistered = false;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (intentIsRegistered==false) {
            registerReceiver(wifiEventReceiver, filter);
            intentIsRegistered = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Manifestation file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.wifitester"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.android.wifitester.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is the log of my app starting and running. I even did a manual scan, still nothing showed up on the debugger.

```
09-04 16:49:21.866    1606-1901/system_process I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.wifitester/.MainActivity bnds=[240,408][240,408]} from pid 25719
09-04 16:49:22.405    1606-1806/system_process I/ActivityManager: Start proc com.android.wifitester for activity com.android.wifitester/.MainActivity: pid=4209 uid=10086 gids={50086, 1028}
09-04 16:49:22.702    4209-4209/com.android.wifitester E/DEBUG: wifi is on
09-04 16:49:22.702    4209-4209/com.android.wifitester E/DEBUG: Scanning has started
09-04 16:49:22.796    4209-4209/com.android.wifitester D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX530_125.so
09-04 16:49:22.843    4209-4209/com.android.wifitester D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX530_125.so
09-04 16:49:22.866    4209-4209/com.android.wifitester D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX530_125.so
09-04 16:49:22.937    4209-4209/com.android.wifitester D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
09-04 16:49:23.038    1606-1622/system_process I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.android.wifitester/.MainActivity: +994ms (total +10s108ms)
```

Comment: do you have appropriate permission?

Comment: Yes. See the manifest.

Comment: The first thing I would do is to rearrange the code. Register the receiver **before** starting the scan.

Comment: Yes, I realized that just after posting the question. Still, no favorable outcome.